# makefile для IAR. Компиляция списка файлов

Tags: makefile, stm32

Здравствуйте.
Есть IDE IAR для STM32.
IDE генерирует конфигурауионный файл *.ewp. По сути, это XML. В нем содержатся сишники, которые учавствуют в проекте. Т.е. физически в папке могут находится несколько исходных файлов, но компилиться будут только те, которые указаны в *.ewp.

Задачка: необходимо написать makefile под linux, который сможет собирать проект IAR.
Я предполагаю, что необходимо будет написать отдельный скрипт, который будет парсить *.ewp и создавать в makefile переменную со списком всех файлов *.c с их путями.

Вопрос. Как использовать переменную

```
SRCP = \
 main.c \
 lib1/src/file1.c \
 lib2/src/file2.c
```

учитывая, что в папках `lib1/src` и `lib2/src` могут находиться еще файлы *.c, которые не должны учавствовать в сборке.

Успешно можно использовать конструкцию `for`:

```
OBJ_DIR = ./Release/Obj
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
$(OBJ): $(SRCP)
    for source in $(SRCP); do \
        $(CC) $(CLAGS) -c $$source -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@; \
    done
```

НО! В консоле при сборке мы не видим название файла `main.c`, а видим слово `$source`. Т.е. это совсем не информативно.
И вообще, я сомневаюсь в правильности конструкции с $@. Почему эта переменная берет каждый раз нужный объект по порядку?

Comment: Сам решил проблему. Посмотреть можно [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130647/makefile-for-iar-list-of-src/48138598#48138598).